# Python Loop with auto creation of data frames

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I am trying to create a loop which will return for each ticker, 
1. a different data frame (by the name of ticker) 
2. with a conversion of the time column to "normal" day 
3. and it (the new time) will be used as index for that data frame.

If I run it for each ticker it's working without problem.
I appreciate your help!

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
desired_width = 320
pd.set_option('display.width', desired_width)

data = pd.DataFrame()
tickers = ['BTC', 'ETH', 'XRP']  # pools of tickers to get
for t in tickers:  # a loop to get data ticker by ticker
        url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday' + \
              '?fsym=' + \
                t +\
              '&tsym=USD' + \
              '&limit=600000000000' + \
              '&aggregate=1' + \
              '&e=CCCAGG'
        response = requests.get(url)
        data[t] = response.json()['Data']
        #the following 2 lines I failed to execute
        #data[t]['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data[t]['time'], unit='s')
        #data[t].index = data[t]['time']
        print("downloading data for: " + t)
        print("data for:" + t, data.head(5))
```

My results is one data frame for all three tickers:

> data for:XRP                                                  BTC
>   ETH                                                XRP 0  {'time':
>   1342742400, 'close': 8.52, 'high': 8....  {'time': 1342742400,
>   'close': 0, 'high': 0, 'l...  {'time': 1342742400, 'close': 0, 'high':
>   0, 'l... 1  {'time': 1342828800, 'close': 8.85, 'high': 9.... 
>   {'time': 1342828800, 'close': 0, 'high': 0, 'l...  {'time':
>   1342828800, 'close': 0, 'high': 0, 'l... 2  {'time': 1342915200,
>   'close': 8.41, 'high': 8....  {'time': 1342915200, 'close': 0, 'high':
>   0, 'l...  {'time': 1342915200, 'close': 0, 'high': 0, 'l... 3 
>   {'time': 1343001600, 'close': 8.45, 'high': 9....  {'time':
>   1343001600, 'close': 0, 'high': 0, 'l...  {'time': 1343001600,
>   'close': 0, 'high': 0, 'l... 4  {'time': 1343088000, 'close': 8.6,
>   'high': 8.8...  {'time': 1343088000, 'close': 0, 'high': 0, 'l... 
>   {'time': 1343088000, 'close': 0, 'high': 0, 'l...

I am using python 3.6 with pycharm + anconda on Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use [`json_normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) for `dinctionary of DataFrame`s with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) for `DataFrame` with `MultiIndex` - first level are `tickers`:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

data = {}
tickers = ['BTC', 'ETH', 'XRP']  # pools of tickers to get
for t in tickers:  # a loop to get data ticker by ticker
        url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday' + \
              '?fsym=' + \
                t +\
              '&tsym=USD' + \
              '&limit=600000000000' + \
              '&aggregate=1' + \
              '&e=CCCAGG'
        response = requests.get(url)
        data[t] = json_normalize(response.json()['Data'])

df = pd.concat(data)
print (df.head())

       close  high   low  open        time  volumefrom    volumeto
BTC 0   8.52  8.87  7.60  8.87  1342742400   154661.12  1267523.74
    1   8.85  9.70  7.96  8.52  1342828800   139906.90  1242153.88
    2   8.41  8.97  8.27  8.85  1342915200    30070.67   259113.81
    3   8.45  9.20  7.75  8.41  1343001600   146396.18  1238579.49
    4   8.60  8.85  8.34  8.45  1343088000    40946.86   353506.54
```

Then for select each level is posible use:

```
print (df.xs('BTC').head())

#print (df.loc['BTC'].head())

   close  high   low  open        time  volumefrom    volumeto
0   8.52  8.87  7.60  8.87  1342742400   154661.12  1267523.74
1   8.85  9.70  7.96  8.52  1342828800   139906.90  1242153.88
2   8.41  8.97  8.27  8.85  1342915200    30070.67   259113.81
3   8.45  9.20  7.75  8.41  1343001600   146396.18  1238579.49
4   8.60  8.85  8.34  8.45  1343088000    40946.86   353506.54
```

Another approach is not `concat`, only create `dictionary`:

```
data = {}
tickers = ['BTC', 'ETH', 'XRP']  # pools of tickers to get
for t in tickers:  # a loop to get data ticker by ticker
        url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday' + \
              '?fsym=' + \
                t +\
              '&tsym=USD' + \
              '&limit=600000000000' + \
              '&aggregate=1' + \
              '&e=CCCAGG'
        response = requests.get(url)
        data[t] = json_normalize(response.json()['Data'])
        data[t] = data[t].set_index(pd.to_datetime(data[t]['time'], unit='s'))

print (data['BTC'].head())

            close  high   low  open        time  volumefrom    volumeto
time                                                                   
2012-07-20   8.52  8.87  7.60  8.87  1342742400   154661.12  1267523.74
2012-07-21   8.85  9.70  7.96  8.52  1342828800   139906.90  1242153.88
2012-07-22   8.41  8.97  8.27  8.85  1342915200    30070.67   259113.81
2012-07-23   8.45  9.20  7.75  8.41  1343001600   146396.18  1238579.49
2012-07-24   8.60  8.85  8.34  8.45  1343088000    40946.86   353506.54
```

EDIT: If want global variable not recommended solution:

```
data = {}
tickers = ['BTC', 'ETH', 'XRP']  # pools of tickers to get
for t in tickers:  # a loop to get data ticker by ticker
        url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday' + \
              '?fsym=' + \
                t +\
              '&tsym=USD' + \
              '&limit=600000000000' + \
              '&aggregate=1' + \
              '&e=CCCAGG'
        response = requests.get(url)
        globals()['df_' + str(t)] = json_normalize(response.json()['Data'])
        globals()['df_' + str(t)] = globals()['df_' + str(t)].set_index(pd.to_datetime(globals()['df_' + str(t)]['time'], unit='s'))

print (df_BTC.head())

            close  high   low  open        time  volumefrom    volumeto
time                                                                   
2012-07-20   8.52  8.87  7.60  8.87  1342742400   154661.12  1267523.74
2012-07-21   8.85  9.70  7.96  8.52  1342828800   139906.90  1242153.88
2012-07-22   8.41  8.97  8.27  8.85  1342915200    30070.67   259113.81
2012-07-23   8.45  9.20  7.75  8.41  1343001600   146396.18  1238579.49
2012-07-24   8.60  8.85  8.34  8.45  1343088000    40946.86   353506.54
```

Comment: thanks! it does solve problems 2 + 3 but not the first which is creating 3 or 99 different data frames each with "df_" + t so I will have df_BTC, df_ETH etc.

Comment: @Giladbi - Is possible use `dictionary of DataFrame`s ?

Comment: But if really need it, then use `globals()['df_' + str(t)] = json_normalize(response.json()['Data'])` instead `data[t] = json_normalize(response.json()['Data'])` and then get `print (df_BTC)`, but it is a bit unpythonic.

Comment: @Giladbi ... it is not advised to store many similar structure objects like dfs in your global environment as it requires too much maintenance and resource pointers. Use **one** container like list or dictionary and you can reference each by unique keys as jezrael shows. The same advice applies for R and other languages!

Comment: @jezrael thanks, it works but i still didn't solve the time format and the time as index. it should be done before the creation of the different data frames. I tried this: response.json()['time'] = pd.to_datetime(data[t]['time'], unit='s') for time format change but i am messing it up.

Comment: Do you want after `data[t] = json_normalize(response.json()['Data'])` add `data[t].index = pd.to_datetime(data[t]['time'], unit='s')` ?

Comment: and then for remove column `time` use `data[t] = data[t].drop('time', 1)`

Comment: I need the time column to be an index and not to drop it and to change it's format. when doing this (as you suggested above) there is no change:  response = requests.get(url)
        data[t] = json_normalize(response.json()['Data'])
        data[t].index = pd.to_datetime(data[t]['time'], unit='s')
        globals()['df_' + str(t)] = json_normalize(response.json()['Data'])

Comment: I get it, you need add after `globals()['df_' + str(t)] = json_normalize(response.json()['Data'])`  this code `globals()['df_' + str(t)] = globals()['df_' + str(t)].set_index(pd.to_datetime(globals()['df_' + str(t)]['time'], unit='s'))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162914/discussion-between-giladbi-and-jezrael).

Comment: So there is problem your dictionary not contains all `tickers`, only last?

Answer (score 0):

I manged to defined a function to get the data and than use a loop to get it for all the tickers. this solves the problem.

```
import requests
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
desired_width = 320
pd.set_option('display.width', desired_width)

#function to download the Historical HOUR data
def hourly_price_historical(symbol, comparison_symbol, limit, aggregate, exchange=''):
    url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histohour?fsym={}&tsym={}&limit={}&aggregate={}'\
            .format(symbol.upper(), comparison_symbol.upper(), limit, aggregate)
    if exchange:
        url += '&e={}'.format(exchange)
    page = requests.get(url)
    data = page.json()['Data']
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df['timestamp'] = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(d) for d in df.time]
    df = df.drop('time', 1)
    df.set_index('timestamp')
    return df


data = {}
tickers = ['BTC', 'ETH', 'XRP']                 # pools of tickers to get
for t in tickers:                                                           # a loop to get data ticker by ticker
    data[t] = hour_data = hourly_price_historical(t,'USD', 9999999,1)       # calling the function defined above
    print("Getting the data for: ", t)
    globals()['df_' + str(t)] = data
```